# Issue with npm install (2/24/2021)

Tags: node.js, npm

I've recently tried running npm install, and for some reason, it does not want to work no matter what I try. I've tried clearing cache, uninstalling and reinstalling Nodejs, adding system32 to the path, all to no progress. Could I get some help? (This same error also comes up if I run 'npm run start')
Below is my error code:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE <br>
npm ERR! syscall spawn cmd <br>
npm ERR! file cmd <br>
npm ERR! path cmd <br>
npm ERR! errno -4058 <br>
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 install: `node scripts/install.js` <br>
npm ERR! spawn cmd ENOENT <br>
npm ERR! <br>
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 install script. <br>
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. <br>
```

Comment: What is the command you are running? Are you in the same folder as your `package.json` file (assuming your are running `npm i`)?

Comment: Yes, running 'npm install' in the folder containing package.json @Brettski

Comment: Sorry, looking for the obvious. I've done it 

Comment: I guess you are facing this issue because node-sass is not properly installed. Delete the package-lock.json file and then run npm install gulp-sass --save-dev, then  npm install node-sass@4.14.1 , aslo please check your current npm version and check the required npm version for node-saas package.

Comment: after doing this, also run npm install to install other dependent modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been quite a while since this question, but the answer was that in following other stack overflow answers for a previous issue, I deleted package-lock.json which came with the clone. Thus, npm was automatically installing the latest versions of each package, rather than the versions the code was made with, causing the errors during the instillation process.